# java.lang.IllegalStateException: chrome The driver is not executable in Jenkins

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I tried all similar questions but I dint get proper answer.
I am using windows and i'm getting following error in Jenkins console when click on build

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable:
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Accessibility
> test/src/main/java/codemantra/ADH/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe

My Original chromedriver path to execute in local was

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

To run from jenkins i copied chromedriver from D: to as below location, but now I am getting the error as driver not executable

I have downloaded latest version of Chromedriver and gave the path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/main/java/codemantra/ADH/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
```

[chromedriver location structure in framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OpXq.png)

Do I need to provide permission to chromedriver in windows and how can I resolve issue

Comment: Can you share your folder structure where you have stored your chromedriver.

Comment: @rahulrai..updated the chrome driver structure

Comment: can you try giving access to directory. Open cmd prompt navigate to folder containing chromedriver and give this command:  chmod 777 chromedriver

Comment: @rahulrai thanks.. Actually I am working on Windows OS. This is a Linux command.i am running on Linux jenkins.But My chromedriver is chromedriver.exe which is suitable for windows.How to set the Linux chromedriver in this case?